# JICOFO: Participant doesn't support bundle, which is required

Tags: video-streaming, video-capture, jitsi, jitsi-meet, jingle

I'm using a custom client to connect to created conference room in jitsi. But I'm getting the following exception:

> org.jitsi.jicofo.AbstractChannelAllocator.log() Error creating offer
>   org.jitsi.jicofo.UnsupportedFeatureConfigurationException: Participant doesn't support bundle, which is required
>       at org.jitsi.jicofo.Participant.setSupportedFeatures(Participant.java:280)
>       at org.jitsi.jicofo.ParticipantChannelAllocator.createOffer(ParticipantChannelAllocator.java:93)
>       at org.jitsi.jicofo.AbstractChannelAllocator.doRun(AbstractChannelAllocator.java:178)
>       at org.jitsi.jicofo.AbstractChannelAllocator.run(AbstractChannelAllocator.java:150)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I'm using LibJitsi (https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi) and jirecon (https://github.com/linhnv5/jirecon). jirecon is the client. Client says

> Could not get session-init packet, maybe the MUC has locked

because of the error from the jicofo and that's the reason jingle session also not establishing.

Can anybody help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. While connecting to jitsi, jicofo looks up for the features of the client/participant supports. It should support RTCP_MUX and RTP_BUNDLE i.e, **urn:ietf:rfc:5761** and **urn:ietf:rfc:5888**. Then only jicofo allows the client/participant to join the room.